# Getting loginStatus from facebook in AngularJS ( returning data in factory )

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs

I'm creating a mobile app in angularJS ( i'm at the very beginning ) and currently trying to get login status from FB API. This is my **app with controller**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);


myApp.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'views/first.html',
        controller: 'FirstCtrl',
        requireLogin : false
    })
    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'views/second.html',
        controller: 'SecondCtrl',
        requireLogin : true
    });
}]);
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope,Auth) {
    $scope.data = Auth.authorize();
});
```

**my factory**

```
myApp.factory('Auth', function() {

    return {
        authorize: function() {
            return FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                 if (response.status == 'not_authorized') {
                     return 'test';
                 }
                 return 'test2';
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**scripts** :

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
            FB.init({
                appId: { my app id }, // App ID
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
                oauth: true
            });

        </script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

and **first.html**

```
Some text, and here is the loginStatus: {{ data }}

<a href='#/second'>Second Page</a>
```

and currently the place with {{ data }} is empty, so I guess the first mistake is way of returning the data in my factory, but I don't really know how to fix this.